# Web audio api analyser node in python

Tags: python, fft, web-audio-api

I try to implement a part of the web audio API in python. Exactly I try to implement the getByteFrequencyData method.

The process is:

- Get data from .wav file or mic
- Apply Blackman window
- Calculate FFT
- Smoothing over time
- conversion to db
- calc the range to 0 -> 255

For my use case, I need this steps except the "Smoothing over time". For me is important when i load a file in the webaudio api and a file in the python version i get the exact same output.

Thats my try, this is not working:

```
import scipy.fftpack as fftpack
from scipy.signal import blackman
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import os
import os.path as path
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
  filePath = path.normpath(path.join(os.getcwd(), '../reference-files/500hz.wav'))
  minDb = -90
  maxDb = -20
  rangeScale = 1 / (maxDb - minDb)

  sampleFreq, samples = wav.read(filePath)     # Load the audio file

  fft_size = 2048                                          # FFT Size
  window = np.blackman(fft_size)                           # Create the window (blackman)
  win_samples = samples[0:fft_size] * window                 # Take a slice and multiply by a window

  fftData = fftpack.fft(win_samples)                           # Calculate the FFT                       # Convert to dbfs#/ freq_range = np.arange((fft_size / 2) + 1) / (float(fft_size) / sampleFreq)       

  # Normalize
  scaledValues = np.array([])

  for i in range(fftData.size):
    dbMag = 20 * np.log10(fftData[i])
    scaledValue = 255 * (dbMag - minDb) * rangeScale

    if (scaledValue < 0):
      scaledValue = 0

    if (scaledValue > 255):
      scaledValue = 255

    scaledValues = np.append(scaledValues, scaledValue)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the link to the Webaudio api code : [Web Audio API - Analyser Node](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/Modules/webaudio/RealtimeAnalyser.cpp)

Update:

Not working: I got another output from the fft as of the web audio api. I think the problem is that is not the same implementation from the fft calculation. I understand how the FFT generally is working but it is a nother story to implement this in code ;-)

Update:

The FFT output is completly different. It looks like this (40.7474782+0.5674489j). I dont know what kind of number this is. I think when the FFT output is correct the other calculations working correctly.

The reason why i will implement this is i need to do some DSP on the client and on the server and this processing needs to base on the same FFT calculation. For simplycity i would use the web audio api for the client side implementation.

For test i use a 500hz sinus wav file.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  What is going wrong with it?

Comment: @MaxvonHippelI have updated the question.

Comment: So "not working" just means that the output from one implementation does not match that from another implementation?  In that case, why would you assume you can exactly replicate someone else's implementation?  Also, can you give us more information about what is different about these two outputs?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel i have updated the questions